# SQL Server Tuning a table for massive inserts

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to solve a performance issue and I need advice.

I have a table, which about twice a day has a massive surge of inserts coming in, and exactly at the same time everybody is trying to read from it. So I have locks and everything becomes painfully slow.

My performance requirements are as follows:

1. many writers, from different sources, and i prefer each write to be atomic.
2. i don't care about the order of the writes, number 7 can come in before number 3.
3. writes should end ASAP, I want writers to wait the least possible amount of time.
4. **data is never updated**, only inserted.
5. I have many many readers.
6. readers want to see the most updated snapshot possible at the time of their read.
7. I can live with readers seeing delayed data (10-20 seconds)
8. I need occasionally do complex and large queries on this data, so i need several indexes on it.

How would you approach this, and how would you implement this with SQL Server?

---

I'm thinking of splitting it into 2 tables... one for the inserts, and one for reading, and a worker moving data.

the large queries will run only on the second, the readers that need updated data, can run on the second, and complete what they need from the first.

Comment: Are writes batched? Or single writes? Any lookup keys to resolve? How many is "massive"?

Comment: writes can't be batched i don't have any other persistence for them. Today there are three indexes covering everything the complex queries require, and a clustered index for the regular readers. Massive is a stock exchange feed massive... or at least that's the goal.

Comment: Stock Exchange prices may or may not be volatile: is it hedge fund flash pricing? Or standard equity EOD prices? Numbers are better too.

Comment: It's not prices, it's transactions and price changes.

Comment: Numbers for performance don't really matter, They are more than we can handle anyway we're going to have to do some sort of sharding eventually...

Comment: Can you drop/disable all the indexes from the table while inserting and enable/re-create them later?

Comment: @asafrob I need the data available constantly. I don't care if i see slightly delayed data, but it must be always there. And were talking about several TB of data.

Comment: What edition of SQL Server (I'm assuming Enterprise, but wanted to be sure)?  And do you have precise times for your data surges, or are they twice a day at unpredictable times?

Comment: Yep SQL Server Enterprise. I can't assume that I know the times, usually it when the markets open, and close, but not always.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One solution I used was to thread out writes to multiple staging tables, then collect the data in batches. We put the staging tables on their own filegroups to try and segregate the I/O as much as possible, though we did end up with two tables on each available LUN, as opposed to each table getting its own dedicated I/O.

Since you said order of writes doesn't matter, this may be viable, but I don't know if 20 seconds will be sufficient to make this work and still not encounter a bunch of blocking.

So let's say we have a base table like this, which is where everyone reads from (and is currently writing to):

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.StockData
(
  StockID INT,
  ...other info...
);
```

Then we have staging tables like this, where we're going to write instead:

```
CREATE TABLE staging.StockData0
(
  StockID INT,
  ...other info...
);

CREATE TABLE staging.StockData1
(
  StockID INT,
  ...other info...
);

... up to StockData9
```

*Don't bother mimicking all of the non-clustered indexes, constraints etc. on these staging tables,

Then assuming you have singleton inserts via a stored procedure, change the stored procedure to use dynamic SQL and insert into one of the 10 tables based on the `StockID` value:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'INSERT staging.StockData'
  + CONVERT(CHAR(1), @StockID % 10 + '(StockID, cols...)
    SELECT @StockID, @params...;';

EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@StockID INT, @params...', @StockID, @params...;
```

Then have a background job that performs a very quick, metadata operation moving these tables into a dummy schema - this minimizes the amount of time that is spent blocking users' ability to write while you move this data into the real table (which you can now control much better than sporadic writes from all over the place). So first create a second copy of the tables in a different schema:

```
CREATE SCHEMA shadow  AUTHORIZATION dbo;
CREATE SCHEMA holding AUTHORIZATION dbo;
GO

CREATE TABLE shadow.StockData0
(
  StockID INT,
  ...other info...
);

-- repeat for 1-9
```

Now the job would do this:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE shadow.StockData0;

BEGIN TRANSACTION;

  ALTER SCHEMA holding TRANSFER staging.StockData0;
  ALTER SCHEMA staging TRANSFER shadow.StockData0;

COMMIT TRANSACTION;

ALTER SCHEMA shadow TRANSFER holding.StockData0;

-- repeat for 1-9 (I actually used dynamic SQL in a loop
-- so I wouldn't have to repeat myself ten times...
```

I blogged about this part of it [here](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/08/t-sql-queries/t-sql-tuesday-schema-switch-a-roo) and [here](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2013/04/t-sql-queries/schema-switch-a-roo-part-2).

The job would then go on to insert *batches* into the primary table, with a delay in between, to allow some reads to happen.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

  INSERT dbo.StockData(StockID, ...cols...)
    SELECT StockID, ...cols...
    FROM holding.StockData0;

COMMIT TRANSACTION;

WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:01';

-- repeat for 1-9
```

This was several years ago, and something that didn't occur to me at the time (which I remember now, too, after seeing the other link posted by wBob) is that using `TABLOCK` inside those transactions may help speed up the inserts (though you'll want to test based on volume, isolation level, etc).

It might also be useful (even with all this work) to enable [Read Committed Snapshot Isolation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188277%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) and/or if you are on Enterprise Edition considering partitioning (and aligning the staging tables to those partitions).

Comment: `ALTER SCHEMA...TRANSFER` ? Never heard of it. Interesting...

Answer (score 2):

The SQL CAT team posted an article on a similar sounding topic:

**Bulk Loading Data into a Table with Concurrent Queries**
http://sqlcat.com/sqlcat/b/technicalnotes/archive/2009/04/06/bulk-loading-data-into-a-table-with-concurrent-queries.aspx